# Keyboard freezing system

Tags: keyboard, freeze

I'm quite new to Linux (Ubuntu) and today I went from virtual machine to dual boot. I've installed Ubuntu 21.04 from the official website, and the keyboard is lagging when typing (even in LiveCD). The mouse doesn't have any problems, but when I type the whole system freezes for 3-4 seconds. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu and it didn't freeze when typing until I restarted the system after updating with  `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

I would be glad for some help, thanks.

Hardware:

- Ryzen 5 3600
- Aorus B450 M (F40 bios)
- 16GB Ram 3200MHz
- RTX 2060GB

Answer (score -1):

Well, without the logs for troubleshooting, i think about this common problems:

Ubuntu freeze when your memory is fully or other system problems. Check the memory use in your vm, not only in your host.
Ubuntu freeze too when the libs for run ubuntu-desktop system is depecrated or bugs in specific libs.

update you repository and reinstall desktop.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help, but i tried to force Wayland (NVIDIA GPU) and it's not happening on Wayland, i could use Wayland, but i cant use NvidiaServer there. So the problem should be XorgServer then, any possible solutions to this? I updated repositories and tried to download all updates.